# Solve differential equations with matrix exponential

Tags: differential-equations

I wanted to solve a differential equations by matrix exponential

```
 A={{-1.30159, 1.47619, 0.47619, 5.36508}, {-0.190476, 0.142857, 
  0.142857, -0.190476}, {1.12698, -0.0952381, 
  0.904762, -2.20635}, {0.52381, 0.857143, -1.14286, -0.47619}}
 Eigenvalues[A];
Matrxiexp = MatrixExp[A t] // Chop // MatrixForm;
Matrixexp = ComplexExpand[Re[MatrixExp[A t] // Chop]];
y[t] = Matrixexp.Subscript[y, 0]
y[t_] = Matrixexp.{a, b, f, g};
Solve[y[t][[1]] == 1, y[0.5][[2]] == -1, y[1.0][[3]] == 2, 
y[1.5][[4]] == -2, {a, b, f, g}]
```

`Options expected (instead of {a,b,f,g}) beyond position 4 in <<1>>
An option must be a rule or a list of rules.`

I have this error when using Solve command, how can I fix these errors

Comment: You use `y` as a function, and then in a subscript. *Don't use subscripts*, they will only cause you trouble like what you have now. Additionally, a group of equations should be enclosed in a list, so do `Solve[{eq1, eq2, (* stuff *)}, (* stuff *)]`

Comment: @J. M. is slightly pensive                                                                              Solve[{y[t], (y[0][[1]] == 1), (y[0.5][[2]] == -1), (y[1.0][[3]] == 
    2), (y[1.5][[4]] == -2), {a, b, f, g}}]                                                             Solve::naqs: <<1>> is not a quantified system of equations and inequalities.

Comment: You changed `y[t][[1]] == 1` to simply `y[t]`, which is not an equation. See http://i.stack.imgur.com/wlLUD.png.  (I changed the name of `Matrixexp` to `expA`, so that it differed from `MatrixExp` by more than a single capitalization.)

Comment: Don't include `MatrixForm` in the definition of variables. All `Form` functions are only meant for printing output, not for doing calculations with.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is too localized; i.e, it applies only to the local situation and needs of its poster. Answers will not benefit others.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After correcting typos, the solution is

```
A = {{-1.30159, 1.47619, 0.47619, 5.36508}, {-0.190476, 0.142857, 
    0.142857, -0.190476}, {1.12698, -0.0952381, 
    0.904762, -2.20635}, {0.52381, 0.857143, -1.14286, -0.47619}};

Matrxiexp = MatrixExp[A t];
y[t_] := MatrixExp[A t].{a, b, f, g};
sol=NSolve[{y[t][[1]] == 1, y[0.5][[2]] == -1, y[1.0][[3]] == 2, 
  y[1.5][[4]] == -2}, {a, b, f, g}];
a/.sol

(*{-(((80.6245 - 
        3.03158*10^-15 I) ((2.23235 + 
          3.55185*10^-16 I) + (1.033 + 1.35031*10^-16 I) 2.71828^(
         3.41222 t) + (1. + 0. I) 2.71828^(
         4.66103 t) - (3.23235 - 6.02587*10^-17 I) 2.71828^(4.12885 t)
          Cos[0.569708 t] + (0.406281 + 4.40032*10^-16 I) 2.71828^(
         4.12885 t) Sin[0.569708 t]))/((-80.746 - 
        7.42086*10^-15 I) + (1. + 0. I) 2.71828^(
       4.66103 t) - (3.53879 - 8.47296*10^-16 I) 2.71828^(4.12885 t)
        Cos[0.569708 t] - (1.33984 - 1.40737*10^-14 I) 2.71828^(
       4.12885 t) Sin[0.569708 t]))}*)
```

Comment: As long as we're fixing the OP's code: the `Eigenvalues[A];` is superfluous, no?

Comment: @J.M.isslightlypensive This is an extra line, I cleaned it up. Perhaps the author was looking for an application for `Eigenvalues[A]`.

Comment: @Alex Trounev thank you

Comment: @MohsenOmrani You are welcome.